# keypress in JQuery Stops Working When Disabling Input Field

Tags: jquery, focus, keypress

I bind a keypress to the document, and in addition to running some command (alert, in this case), I also have it disable an input box.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    alert("escape pressed");
    $("#inputField").attr('disabled','disabled');
   }
  });
  </script>

  <input type="text" id="inputField" />
```

The problem is if I press escape inside `inputField`, escape no longer triggers the alert unless I manually click inside the page again.

Does anyone know why this is or how else I can disable an input box with a keypress without losing my focus on the window?

Comment: If inputField is disabled, how are you clicking in it? http://jsfiddle.net/65utT/ seems to work using your code. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi j08691, in that fiddle you made, click somewhere off the input field, and press escape.  A popup comes up.  Click "ok" to clear it, and repeat.  It works no problem.  Now, refresh and click inside the input box (initially enabled), and press escape.  The popup comes up.  Click "ok" to clear it and press escape again.  Nothing (until you manually click on the page somewhere).  That's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a Firefox specific issue. Focus is getting locked in the disabled textbox and keypresses are not getting triggered, but Tab key is working. 
In Chrome keypress events are occuring properly after disabling the text box.
Anyway you can use `tabIndex` property and set focus to some other element before disabling the text box.

```
 $("#cover").focus();
 $("#inputField1").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 alert("enter pressed");
```

see a demo here: 
(*escape key is not working in Chrome I have changed it to enter key*)
http://jsfiddle.net/diode/4Xvqj/show

..

Comment: It works!  I've never even heard of `tabIndex` before.  Thanks!  Also, I deleted the second input field and the `tabIndex` on the input, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/h7ZN4/).

Comment: `tabIndex` is actually the order used when user navigates using tab key. Focus will ignore elements like `div` if we don't set tabIndex.

Answer (score 0):

#### Description

Use jQuery's `.keyup()` method. You also forget to wait till the DOM is fully available. You can set the focus to the body element in your `.keyup()` method.

Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/FNgqf/2/)

#### Sample

```
$(function() {
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    alert("escape pressed");
    $("#inputField").attr('disabled','disabled');
    $("body").focus();
   }    
  });
});
```

### Update

The jQuery function `.focus()` does not work on every element, **body** on firefox for example. You can try to set the focus on a other element on your page.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but it has the same problem.  See the response I put under the original post to exactly simulate what's wrong in the fiddle.  Sorry for not being clear to begin with.

Comment: Hi dknaack, I tried many things along those lines (window, body, document, etc) to no avail.  The updated fiddle you linked to isn't working for me.  I also tried doing it in raw javascript (no jQuery), but that didn't work either.  Any other ideas?

Comment: What is not working ? If you press escape in the input box the event get fired. If you press again escape (without clicking) the event gets fired again. I am confused ;)

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox. It only works on the first "esc" press; subsequent "esc" presses don't do anything until I click in the body.  Does anybody have anything ideas how to do this in Firefox?  Much obliged,

Comment: My answer is updated again. Please try to `.focus()` on a other element of your page.

Comment: Hi dknaack, thanks for your update, but focusing on a different dummy div doesn't work, either.  I've tried this with different permutations of keypress/down/up as well.  I think I'm stumped here.

Comment: Yes a div doesnt work too. I have tried several element types. Do you have another input element (not hidden) ?

Comment: It doesn't work (as you suggested) with visibility:hidden or display:none or <input type="hidden">, and I don't have another text input to work with, but it does work with an <a href=...>, so I think I might have to use that.  It's too bad though, because I'm working on my first deployable chat based website and this feels like such a hack.  If anyone comes up with anything different please post!

Comment: As long firefox does not support that, i think, you must doing a "hack".